# Why int allocates 8 bytes by default?

Tags: c++, memory-management, integer

when I try to allocate memory in c++ it allocates 8 bytes by default I expected 4;

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int* arr = new int;


    cout << "arr " << sizeof(arr)<<endl;

    cout << "int16 " << sizeof(int16_t)<<endl;
    cout << "int32 " << sizeof(int32_t)<<endl;
    cout << "int64 " << sizeof(int64_t)<<endl;
}
```

this is a result:

```
arr 8
int16 2
int32 4
int64 8
```

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` is the size of the *pointer*, not the thing it points at.

Comment: the amount of memory allocated by new is almost always larger than the type being allocated - allocation in blocks is  how dynamic memory allocation works. but there is no way of finding out the block size for a particular allocation

Comment: @NeilButterworth I don't think this has anything to do with the behavior of `sizeof`, which is a compile-time construct.

Comment: @wohlstad the question was "why int allocates 8 bytes" - i was pointing out that probably no such allocation occurs.

Comment: @NeilButterworth OP did mention the allocation size, but their code is about the behavior of `sizeof`. This is at least my understanding, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(arr)` is the size of the `int*`. You're most likely compiling/executing for a 64bit architecture, so pointers are 8 bytes in size.

Dereferencing like `sizeof(*arr)` prints the size of `int` which is `4` as expected

Comment: Thank you but for this question stack overflow banned me to ask questions any more because of the reputation so doesn't meter